# Does background audio work without .longFormAudio policy on WatchOS?

Tags: ios, core-audio, apple-watch, avaudiosession, watchos

Does anyone know wether audio can be both recorded and played back in the background on the Apple Watch?

It's possible to playback audio in the background by adding the .longFormAudio policy on the audio session however this does not work with the .playAndRecord mode.

I'd like to be able to record audio from the device's microphone then play it back either through the device speaker or paired Bluetooth headphones.

The audio will also need to continue recording and playing if the user lowers their wrist and the watch display turns off.